# How to move a directory to newly mounted drive?

Tags: linux, mount, fdisk

What is the easier way to move a directory to newly mounted drive

Example, if I have a directory called /example and mounted a new drive to /vol, how I can easily move /example to /vol

Since database data is stored in /example, if I copy the folder it might just get corrupted.

Thanks

Comment: Why would the data get corrupted exactly??

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 5):

`mv /example /vol`

(Works in Linux, BSDs, most Unix flavors, and Windows PowerShell)

Answer (score 2):

1. Shut down database (or any other service depending on /example)
2. `mv /example/* /vol/`
3. `rm -rf /example`
4. Either reconfigure your database/applications to use /vol, or create a symlink with `ln -s /vol /example`

Answer (score 1):

Moving the data directory should be ok as long as the database is shut down before the move occurs.

Move all files in /example into /vol:

```
mv /example/* /vol
```

Files will be directly under /vol.

Move /example directory inside /vol:

```
mv /example/ /vol
```

Files will be under /vol/example.

Comment: You've got the same command up there twice...

Comment: His 2nd eg shouldn't have the `/*`.